# Does a Ranged Basic Attack with range Melee become a Melee Basic Attack?

Tags: dnd-4e

Divine Bolts as modified by Power Of Skill:

> You can use any power you have that is associated with this feat as a basic attack.

Is treated as a basic attack, and because it's ranged, is treated as a ranged basic attack.

The paragon feat: Staff of Channeled Invocations:

> Benefit: When you use any ranged invoker attack power through a staff, you can use the power as a melee attack with a range of 1.

Does this channeled divine bolts then count as a melee basic attack?

Comment: You like that divine bolts, no? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/how-do-i-integrate-an-implement-based-ranged-basic-attack-with-the-hunters-rapid

Comment: It's a very useful power :) I really love the invoker at-wills and really hate the rest of the class. Which... is annoying.

Comment: Could we think the other way around? That is: The Staff allow us to use Dive Bolts as a melee 1 attack. Then, Power of Skill allow us to treat the power associated power (now a melee attack) as a basic melee attack.

Comment: oooh, that's a good interpretation. post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could face the question the other way around.

The Staff of Channeled Invocations allows us to use *Divine Bolts* as a melee 1 attack.
Then, Power of Skill allows us to treat the associated power (now a melee attack) as a basic melee attack.

Answer (score 4):

This boils down to: Is a "melee, basic attack" a "**Melee Basic Attack**"

As written, there is a *tiny* amount of wiggle room to say no, but it's pretty hard for me to read that as anything other than you've managed to make divine bolts usable as a melee basic attack.

Comment: And you make your Warlord happy when you melee basic against 1 or 2 enemies :)

Comment: Eeeh, it's actually quite hard to set up such that the targetting of the calling power doesn't override the fiddly bits. I'm just thinking about the bladesinger. Mind you, that's a fairly stupid feat investment...

Comment: @Brian - I see what you mean - most of the Warlords basic attack granting powers specify the target of the basic attack.